# Правка не должна прерывать проверку в очереди на закрытие

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

Сейчас в очереди проверок работает следующая схема:

1. Вопрос попадает в очередь по одному голосу за закрытие.
2. Дальше он проходит ещё четверых проверяющих и каждый может проголосовать: <kbd>закрыть</kbd> или <kbd>оставить открытым</kbd> ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/61635))
3. Если один из проверяющих выбирает <kbd>отредактировать</kbd>, то проверка досрочно завершается. ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/62103) - прервана проверка, инициированная "дубликатом")

Если правка косметическая (форматирование), то вряд ли вопрос от этого становится более отвечаемым.

Если вопрос был отмечен как дубликат, то далеко не всегда правка делает его не-дубликатом. (Вообще очень редко).

Поэтому правка не должна прерывать проверку. Пускай она засчитывается как <kbd>оставить открытым</kbd>. Следующие проверяющие будут видеть вопрос в новой редакции и если правка действительно сделала его отвечаемым, то они тоже выберут <kbd>оставить открытым</kbd>. В истории такая правка может отражаться как `оставить открытым и редактировать`

Comment: Опа! Не знал о такой особенности. Неожиданно.

Comment: @VenZell возобновите там проверку, если не трудно )

Comment: Уже проголосовал